# Error: expected abstract interface package-info {}

Tags: java, compilation

We are working on java classes in order to customize it. Before this customization, we just want to check compile/decompile process of existing java jar file (MMC.jar).

We collected all java class file under MMC.jar using jd-gui tool

So when we were compiling the existing MMC.jar (without customization) it is giving attached 6 errors

```
./com/mmc/model/acknowledgement/package-info.java:7: error: illegal start of     
type abstract interface package-info {}
                      ^
./com/mmc/model/acknowledgement/package-info.java:7: error: = expected
abstract interface package-info {}
                            ^
./com/mmc/model/customer/package-info.java:7: error: <identifier> expected
abstract interface package-info {}
              ^
./com/mmc/model/customer/package-info.java:7: error: illegal start of type
abstract interface package-info {}
                      ^
./com/mmc/model/customer/package-info.java:7: error: = expected
abstract interface package-info {}
                            ^
6 errors
```

This is the content of package-info java file

```
package com.mmc.model.customer;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;

@XmlSchema(namespace="http://www.iflex.com/mmc/model/customer",    
elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
abstract interface package-info {}
```

Regards
Ali

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why package-info.java file? What is the use of package-info.java class file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940585/why-package-info-java-file-what-is-the-use-of-package-info-java-class-file)

Comment: I guess you won't need package-info.java. just delete it

Comment: @sidgate That sounds like a good mantra: "if you don't know what package-info.java is; then you do not need it".

Comment: I have updated the post with the content of file package-info

Answer (score 0):

The reason you've got compilation error is **package-info** is not allowed identifier. You cannot name objects like classes, interfaces, variables, etc, with **-** character. See this answer for more detail [Naming rules](https://www.quora.com/What-are-variable-naming-rules-in-Java).

But the problem is that you use package info file in wrong way. The aim of **package-info.java** file is to add brief description of package in javadoc: what the purpose of this package, responsibilities and contents. You shouldn't declare any classes or interface here. All you need to write in this file is package name in which this file located and package summary javadoc. A @sidgate comment refers to a good answer about package info file responsibility.